# Javascript: Adding/Subtracting to 'top' attribute to elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add some pixels from an element on my page. This is so I can create a new element and place it above it.

```
 posy = document.getElementById('user').style.top + 20;
```

But it is returning "50px20", I haven't tried subtracting it yet, but what should I do to prevent it from returning 'px' in it?

Is there a way to do this in jQuery?

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking is a little confusing. You say you want the `top` attribute, but this could be the position of the element on the page or the top value of its style. There is a distinct difference. It sounds like you want the position of the element because you are storing the results in `posy`. This is different than getting the top value of the CSS which will only exist if it has been defined in your stylesheet.

To get the `top` CSS value in jQuery you would use

```
$('selector').css('top');
```

To get the position of the element use jQuery's `offset()` or `position()` methods. You probably would want offset.

```
$('selector').offset().top; //or .left
```

To fix your returned value for `px` or `em` try parseInt.

```
parseInt(value);
```

Comment: Thanks 'mate! Sorry about not explaining enough, but it worked perfect!

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript's `+` operator performs concatenation of strings as well as adding of Numbers. This can be pretty confusing, but once you know, it's easy to solve using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
var posy = parseInt(document.getElementById('user').style.top, 10) + 20;
```

One other quirk: `parseInt(number)` doesn't always work as expected. If `number` is a string of a number start starts with a leading zero (like `0123`), parseInt will assume it is in base 8.

To make sure it works as expected, use `radix`: `parseInt(number, 10);`

P.S.: [mrtsherman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8867906/990877) has a good point about your underlying intent. And while I agree with his advise to use jQuery, it *is* possible with plain JavaScript as well:

```
function findOffsetTop(element) {
    var offset = 0;
    do {
        offset += element.offsetTop;
    } while (element = element.offsetParent);
    return offset;
}

var user = document.getElementById('user');
var posy = findOffsetTop(user) + 20;
```

*(Based on http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html)*

Comment: This also helped me very well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
posy = parseInt($('#user').css('top').replace('px', ''), 10) + 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain Javascript method:

`posy = document.getElementById('user').style.top.replace('px','') + 20;`

jQuery method:

`posy = $('user').css('top').replace('px','')+20;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
posy = parseInt(document.getElementById('user').style.top) + 20;
```